# Defining custom word wrap boundaries in Swift

Tags: swift2, uilabel, word-wrap

Setting the word wrap on a UILabel is quite easy; however, I am having issues with attributed strings that contain multiple "items" to be displayed in a single label, including icons with font awesome.

Each item will include a number of components that should be grouped together. For example:

(T) 20 :icon:

Based on actual size of text, only small parts of the above example will word wrap; I need it to word wrap the entire grouping of text. Is this possible?

I would likely need to somehow define a custom character range for word wrap but I do not think this is natively supported. Any thoughts would be great, Thanks!